# maybe sumis multiple criteria in one column (index match) 2 files

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I would like to ask for advice which is the best function to use:

one file I have months projects and accounts for external services - for example 06 2016 projects bg.01 bg 02 bg 03

In second file I have months projects accounts sum

```
╔═══════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════╗
║ month ║ project ║ account ║ sum  ║
╠═══════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════╣
║     7 ║ bg01    ║  615600 ║ 2000 ║
║     7 ║ bg02    ║  615610 ║ 3500 ║
║     7 ║ bg01    ║  616400 ║ 3600 ║
║     7 ║ bg03    ║  615600 ║ 2100 ║
║     7 ║ bg01    ║  616400 ║ 3800 ║
║     7 ║ bg02    ║  602300 ║ 3500 ║
║     7 ║ bg01    ║  615600 ║ 1000 ║
╚═══════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════╝
```

so I have to sum for example accounts 615600 + 616400 by projects and months and fill in the first file

I apprecialte any advice

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is difficult to understand what you are explaining. Your example of "06 2016 projects" doesn't make sense because the only date in your example table is "7". Maybe if you tell us what you have tried, it will help us understand?

Comment: Also, I suggest you look at using a [pivot table](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) to summarize data. They are great tools for what you seek to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thank you for welcoming and sorry for not posting clearly enough So the 1st file I have to fill in is as follows: (there the result from sumifs should appear)

month   year project   external services (sum) internal sum provisions sum

2        2016    bg02
3        2016    bg01
7        2016    bg01
7        2016    bg03
7        2016    bg02

And column external services is the sum of the accounts from the first table (for example 615600+615610); provisions - sum of the accounts (602300 + 616400) I need for example sumif in cell D2 - to be seen the sum of accounts 615600+615610 match by project and month; in d3 sumifs accounts 602300+616400 again by project and month
 I hope now is more clear